# What Should I do with this Cordova Build Error?

Tags: cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build my cordova app, but I get this error, what should I do?

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Cordova\\App\\platforms\\android\\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Cordova\\App\\platforms\\android\\build.gradle
```

I tried to see if there is some gradle missing file, but I don't understand, I am a begginer, especially with Cordova

Comment: build doing cordova build [platform] --verbose to get more info

Comment: I think there should probably more information higher up in the logs that points you to the actual error message

Comment: @Mister_CK yes there are more informations but this site didn't let me insert the whole code in the question, anyways i am using android studio now, so i think i will continue with that